# How to display an image in Octave with original aspect ratio and size?

Tags: octave

I want to display an image in octave without being scaled (i.e. one image pixel maps to exactly one pixel of my monitor) or having a wrong aspect ratio. Unfortunately neither `imshow()`, `imagesc()` or `image()` do that automatically. But it must be possible, right?
I'm using Octave 3.2.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a couple ways to do this. Here's 2 of them:

1. run `daspect ([1 1])` after displaying the image;
2. use set to change some properties of the image `set (gca, "Position", [0 0 1 1])`

Comment: Running `imshow(randn([20 30])), daspect ([1 1]), set (gca, "Position", [0 0 1 1])` I get a scaled-up image. What I'd want (and what I think this question asks for) would be a tiny 20x30 image with one monitor pixel per image pixel. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I think I got it now. I need to set the figure's position in pixels to the appropriate size, in addition to `set (gca, "Position", [0 0 1 1])`

Answer (score 1):

I find that in Octave 3.8.1 (running the distro version from Linux Mint 17), using `axis tight normal` will produce a well-behaved graph similar to the standard Matlab output.  YMMV.